# Caches "reload" in TYPO3?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have an installation of TYPO3, it's made by the introduction bundle and the bootstrap_package. According to an issue on github (bootstrap_package) concerning custom styles, I add the code

```
page.includeCSS {
  mycustomstyles = fileadmin/custom.css
}
```

to the setup section of the template (I'm not a TYPO3 pro obviously).

That works, but after a while (even after doing nothing over the night) this CSS file is not linked anymore. Then I have to flush the caches to get it back working.

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "not linked"?

Comment: Can you check the source code on frontend, if the file is included from its original location or is it merged with other CSS files and included from different location?

Comment: That is axactly what I ment by "linked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that you are able to track down that css file from your browser console, add this to your page setup:

```
config.compressCss = 0
config.concatenateCss = 0
```

Also, where did you include that typoscript? For starters, it should be in the page template setup for your root page, so it can take effect over all the child pages.

In case this is an actual caching issue you could disable the cache with

```
config.cache = 0
```

and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This can be useful for troubleshooting but usually not recommended as permanent solution for production (because of performance). config.cache=0 disables page cache for all pages (or all subpages of page where your configured this if configured in Template record for a page).

Comment: Thanks for making this clear @SybillePeters indeed none of those setting are recommended for production, and they exist mainly for the sake of debugging.